# Elasticsearch - Is it possible to have the index and type with same name?

Tags: elasticsearch

The question is in the title.
I'm wondering if there would be any issue if my index and my type (within that index) have the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's a simple check (just try to create :P):

```
post /test/test
{
    "test":"test"
}
```

Edit:
There will not be any side effects from the Elasticsearch point of view. I can see some side effects in normal conversation between developers so it's more connected with a naming strategy.

Comment: I did and know that it's fine. My question was if this would have any side effects. Thanks anyway :)